# imports in NAMESPACE does need also be in DESCRIPTION?

Tags: r

If I add imports in NAMESPACE for instance:

```
importFrom("stats", "cutree", "dist", "hclust")
```

Do I also need to add library `imports: stats` to DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Yes, you need to

Comment: Thx, and is the spellin OK?

Comment: It's `Imports: stats`, I believe. (capital first letter)

Comment: All of this is explained on the relevant documentation. Please read Writin R Extensions.